# codeigniter : anchor link not working in localhost but index page executes fine

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I downloaded a old webpage from webserver. now i am redesign all pages. while testing the links get back to localhost content page. but it works fine in web server.

in localhost index page works fine but from index page links are not working.
while click links the url shows fine like

```
http://localhost/sitename/site/index
```

anchor code in home page is :

```
<?php echo  anchor(base_url().'site/index','Home','class="header"');?>
```

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sitename/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in controller (site.php):

```
class Site extends CI_Controller    
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');    
    $this->load->helper('html');        
}

public function index()
{       
    $this->load->view('site/home');     
}
}
```

.htaccess page on www/site-folder-name

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

if u want any other detail i will give u....

Comment: I think this issue might occurs due to your `.htaccess` or try to make your `$config['base_url']="";`

Comment: why we need htaccess, i was tried with `$config['base_url']="";` but same issue.

Comment: It brings all the request to your application root `index.php` file than routing is perform from their to output specified controller and specified method in your url.

Comment: .htaccess also i given now and inside of htaccess is `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>`  but same issue

Comment: add this line `RewriteBase /sitename` after `RewriteEngine on` in your `.htaccess` it might work.

Comment: Try to Change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` and remove space betweeen `/ foldersite-name`

Comment: i updated `.htaccess` again, can u chack with that pls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68706/discussion-between-indrasinh-bihola-and-nagaraj-raju).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /project_name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```